# Delete lines up to regexp with sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I want to use a sed or gawk/awk command that will find a regexp:

```
TRAFFIC
```

and combine it with the following unix command, or similar command, that renders the sysdate minus one day:

```
date "--date=${dataset_date} -${date_diff} 1 day" +%d%b%Y
```

and then delete all lines between regexp and the sysdate minus one day.

Sample of File Input:

```
TYPE = REGIONAL                              (keep)
TRAFFIC AND LOGISTICS                        (keep)
                                             (delete)
DATE                                         (delete)
01AUG18                                      (delete)
TIME          TRA            NDFV            (delete)
00:00-00:15    0.00           0              (delete)
00:15-00:30    0.00           0              (delete)
00:30-00:45    0.00           1              (delete)
DATE                                         (delete)
02AUG18                                      (keep - sysdate minus one day)
TIME          TRA            NDFV            (keep)
00:00-00:15    0.00           2              (keep)
00:15-00:30    0.00           0              (keep)
00:30-00:45    0.00           0              (keep)
00:45-01:00    0.00           0              (keep)
```

Sample of File Output:

```
TYPE = REGIONAL
TRAFFIC AND LOGISTICS
02AUG18    
TIME          TRA            NDFV 
00:00-00:15    0.00           2   
00:15-00:30    0.00           0   
00:30-00:45    0.00           0   
00:45-01:00    0.00           0
```

In this case `02AUG18` would be the sysdate minus one day. Normally there would be many more lines in between the regexp and the sysdate minus one to delete. Is it possible to combine a command such as:

```
sed '/TRAFFIC/,/ [sysdate minus one day] /d'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try awk:

```
d=$( date -d yesterday "+%d%b%y" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' )
awk -v date="$d" '$1 == date {del = 0}; !del; /TRAFFIC/ {del = 1}'
```

Comment: It looks like the `d=` line is to name a variable, so I tried adding `t1>t2` for my input and output files on the awk line but it deleted everything after TRAFFIC.  Another suggestion please?

Comment: If today was August 3rd, this would work for your sample text. But it is not Aug 3

Comment: I tried using a `sed` command I'd gotten from someone else, but I still can't get it to work, so it looks like `awk` is the winner of the week.

Answer (score 0):

Print the first two lines, then print a range from the sysdate -1 to another DATE:

```
sed -n -e '1,2p' -e "/$(date -v-1d  +%d%b%y | tr -s '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')/,/DATE/p"
```

output:

```
TYPE = REGIONAL                              (keep)
TRAFFIC AND LOGISTICS                        (keep)
20AUG18                                      (keep - sysdate minus one day)
TIME          TRA            NDFV            (keep)
00:00-00:15    0.00           2              (keep)
00:15-00:30    0.00           0              (keep)
00:30-00:45    0.00           0              (keep)
00:45-01:00    0.00           0              (keep)
```

Point being, yes, you can pass expressions to sed; in this case as part of the  range. Note: (1) I assumed there might be another DATE beyond second one and therefore closed off the range with a DATE, but you might want something else.

Comment: `-v` for date? is that BSD/OSX?

Comment: @glennjackman yep.  Adjusts the second, minute, hour, month day, week day, month or year according to val.